# Не могу подключиться к gitlab по SSH, почему?

Tags: linux, git, gitlab

Есть развернутый на своем сервере гитлаб, он успешно работает, выгружаются проекты, все создается, веб-интерфейс тоже работает.
Раньше не так часто приходилось выгружать проекты, так как почти не было правок, поэтому при выгрузке в гитлаб - просто вводили логин и пароль.
Сейчас появилась потребность в частых коммитах, и вводить логин и пароль часто не очень удобно.
Решил настроить авторизацию через SSH ключ.

Для чистоты удалял все из папки .ssh и делал все с нуля.
Делаю по следующему алгоритму:

1. Создаю ключ следующей командой: ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/gitlab
2. Копирую данные из файла gitlab.pub и вставляю их в gitlab, ключ
   успешно добавляется
3. Пытаюсь клонировать проект запрашивает пароль, пытался вводить
   пароль от своего пользователя - пароль не верный

Команда ssh -v git@gitlab.iso-team.ru выдает следующее:
OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n 7 Dec 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for gitlab.iso-team.ru
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for 

*debug1: Connecting to gitlab.iso-team.ru [45.80.69.169] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug1: identity file /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/gitlab type 0

debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory

debug1: identity file /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/gitlab-cert type -1

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3

debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab.iso-team.ru:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:jn3djC8AvaKRIeHzBy4wFFu1pl7TKuMDEwbreaZ5Qbs
debug1: Host 'gitlab.iso-team.ru' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:7rdux0TUfos0dlwQomw4RxqaJfxIbT4YmtcTfSFhIak /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/gitlab
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password

Answer (score 2):

**Всем выражаю большую благодарность** за помощь, каждый совет однозначно помог. 
Решение оказалось как всегда на поверхности. 
Все дело было в том, что файл sshd_config **на сервере**, который находится по следующему пути: /etc/ssh в строчке AllowUsers содержал всего одного доступного пользователя, добавил пользователя git, под которым происходит авторизация и все стало работать. 
Строка AllowUsers после внесения изменений стал выглядеть вот так: 
`AllowUsers youruser git`

Расписываю алгоритм более подробно, на случай если кто-то столкнется с такой проблемой.

1. Открываем файл sshd_config на сервере, который находится по следующему пути /etc/ssh
2. Ищем строку AllowUsers, скорее всего там будет прописан ваш пользователь под которым обычно происходит авторизация по SSH. Добавляем через пробел пользователя git и строка получается вот такой: AllowUsers youruser git
   Сохраняем изменения
3. Перезагружаем sshd командой: sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart
4. Получаем ключ для Gitlab, много где описано как это сделать, я сделал следующим образом: 
   Вводим команду на локальной машине, с которой будете работать: 
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/gitlab
   После переходим в папку .ssh и копируем ключ из файла gitlab.pub, идем в веб-интерфейс gitlab и войдя под нужным пользователем добавляем ему ключ.
5. Теперь создадим файл config на локальной машине в папке .ssh, он нужен, чтобы указать какой ключ для какого соединения применять, так как подключение на сервер у нас происходит тоже по SSH. 
   Данный файл получился вот такого содержания:
    

   `Host 45.80.69.169
       IdentityFile /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/id_rsa
       port 22
   Host gitlab.iso-team.ru
       IdentityFile /home/kramdmitriy/.ssh/gitlab
       port 22`

   Первый ключ - это ключ для сервера, второй для гитлаба.
   Сохраняем файл и пробуем подключиться к gitlab по SSH

Comment: Спасибо, крутое решение, совершенно не лежащее на поверхности, и очень хорошо, что Вы его нашли. Думаю, мы просто по разному устанавливали gitlab, я ставил его явно каким то скриптом (omnibus?), в котором эта особенность, скорее всего, была учтена. Уверен, что такое решение еще пригодится в других случаях.

Answer (score 0):

Очень знакомая ситуация.

С этой авторизацией по ключам всегода просто голову сломаешь, пока заработает.

Я предлагаю следующее: давайте сравним файлы на клиенте и на сервере?

У меня есть работающий gitlab, на котором я когда то настроил авторизацию. При этом у меня в гитлаб импортирован ключ, а на клиенте в папке .ssh есть следующие файлы:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
known_hosts
```

И у меня работает всё, что связано с клонированием, коммитами и т.п. по протоколу ssh.

Но! Залогиниться пользователь сервера, котрого я создал на gitlab, по ssh не может. я ПОДОЗРЕВАЮ что для таких пользователей просто нет  прав на interactive login.

При попытке залогтниться по ssh с ключем -v происходит вот что:

```
ssh -v konst-developer@gitlab0.junecat.ru
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to gitlab0.junecat.ru [192.168.10.57] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to gitlab0.junecat.ru:22 as 'konst-developer'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8dMOgDXYjZWRj+bqEacWKTt00uppdB1A2cL/0GL4Ua8
debug1: Host 'gitlab0.junecat.ru' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/davydov/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
konst-developer@gitlab0.junecat.ru's password:
```

Навскидку - возмжны следующие проблемы:

1) неправильный тип ключа. Что то типа того, что очень современный гитлаб требует ключей не менее какой то длинны. Но это он должен был бы сказать в явном виде при импорте ключа.

2) Неправильные (слишком "широкие") права на приватную часть ключа. Но при этом git clone ругалась бы ЯВНО намекая на то, что права неправильные

3) предлагаю эксперимент: у Вас есть ключ - приватная и публичная часть. Создайте в вируалочке маленький линуксовый сервачок и настройте на нём авторизацию при ssh - логине ПО ЭТИМ САМЫМ КЛЮЧАМ. (как это сделать - гуглится, например, здесь: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ssh-ubuntu-18-04-ru). Если авторизация заработает - значит, дело не в ключах, а в гитлабе. Возможно, ему протсо не хватает какой то галочки, тем более что там от версии к версии интерфейс меняется, видно, есть специальные люди для этого в команде :-)

Если могу Вас навести еще на какие то мысли - пишите, постараюсь помочь

Comment: Есть "яркая идея" как ОБОЙТИ эту проблему: в клиенте github desktop есть ткая примочка - credential manager, она предназначена именно для того, чтобы запомниать пароли, котторые вводятся ПО HTTPS. При этом этого клиента не обязательно заставлять работать с github, он работает с любым гитом. Можно просто дать ему запомнить все пароли - и пусть он их вводит.

Comment: @s-h, большое спасибо за подробный ответ! Попробую все варианты и обязательно отпишусь о результате.

Comment: @s-h, спасибо большое за помощь. Решение нашел, описал его выше.